# Lithium PHP on Heroku

Tags: php, heroku, lithium

I am trying to deploy a Lithium app on Heroku, but Heroku uses a read-only file system for apps.  This causes a problem with the app/resources folder.  I've tried looking for a setting the lithium config to change the path to this folder, but it appears to be hard coded.

Can anyone recommend how to resolve this issue?

Comment: I can't tell from the Lithium docs what it does with the `app/resources` folder. Could you clarify? You need to write some data there and you're getting an error message? If so, what's the error message? Or do you mean you can write data there just fine but that data gets destroyed when your app is restarted each day?

Answer (score 0):

Lithium uses the `/resources` folder for writing temporary files such as logs, file caches, compiled PHP templates, etc.

The path is configurable through `Libraries::add()` when the application is initialized. In `config/bootstrap/libraries.php`, you can replace your application's `Libraries::add()` call with one like the following: https://github.com/orchestra-io/sample-lithium/blob/master/app/config/bootstrap/orchestra.php#L10

This configuration uses the system's temp directory, and checks for/initializes the subdirectories Lithium will use.